# Pandas matplotlib.pyplot add legend by a column value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image]I'm using Pandas to make a scatter plot. My data look like this:

```
    Locations Lenovo Global Region Primary Function Subsidiaries Apr_2015_to_Mar_2016_[kWh] Apr_2015_to_Mar_2016_[MT] color MT/kWh
<!-- -->  

    263 United Kingdom - Hook EMEA Large Office (OFL) Lenovo 7.561727e+04 129.438515 r 0.001712  
    202 South Africa - Johannesburg/Bryanston EMEA Small Office (OSL) Lenovo 1.013746e+05 93.872885 r 0.000926  
    232 India - Chennai Factory Asia Pacific Manufacturing (MFG) Motorola Mobility 3.163600e+05 271.933953 g 0.000860  
    159 India - Pondicherry Asia Pacific    Manufacturing (MFG) Lenovo  1.074016e+06    907.869649  g   0.000845  
    242 Australia - Chatswood   Asia Pacific    Large Office (OFL)  Lenovo  3.001254e+05    239.500093  g   0.000798
```

define a function to use different color for different regions.

```
def colorpoint(row):
    if row['Lenovo Global Region'] == 'Asia Pacific':
        return('g')
    if row['Lenovo Global Region'] == 'EMEA':
        return('r')
    else:
        return('b')
test3['color'] = test3.apply (lambda row: colorpoint (row),axis=1)
```

define the scatter points that I want to plot.

```
y=test3['Apr_2015_to_Mar_2016_[MT]']
x=test3['Apr_2015_to_Mar_2016_[kWh]']
T = test3['color']
area= (y/x)*500000
xmax=1.1*max(test3['Apr_2015_to_Mar_2016_[kWh]'])
ymax=1.1*max(test3['Apr_2015_to_Mar_2016_[MT]'])
```

plot the figure. 
    fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9), dpi=300)
    ax = plt.subplot(111)

```
plot=plt.scatter(x,y,alpha=0.6,c=T,s=area)
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlim([0,xmax])
ax.set_ylim([0,ymax])
ax.set_xlabel('Apr 2015 to Mar 2016 [kWh]')
ax.set_ylabel('Apr 2015 to Mar 2016 [MT]')
ax.set_title('Total Elec consumtion [kWh] VS CO2 emission [MT]')
```

Try to add legend. 
**I want to show colors correspond to their "Lenovo Global Region", but it's not working, only showing one region "America Groups" as blue dot**

```
legend=test3['Lenovo Global Region']
plt.legend(legend,loc=4)
```

Thanks if you have ideas!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need in the last line:

```
plt.legend(legend.values,loc=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for city,color in [('Asia Pacific', 'Green'), ('EMEA', 'Red'), ('rest', 'Blue')]:
    x = test3.loc[test3['Lenovo Global Region']==city]['Apr_2015_to_Mar_2016_[kWh]']
    y = test3.loc[test3['Lenovo Global Region']==city]['Apr_2015_to_Mar_2016_[MT]']
    area= (y/x)*500000
    plt.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.6,c=color,s=area, label=city)
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 1):

From this other question that might be the same:
[Matplotlib adding legend based on existing color series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595288/matplotlib-adding-legend-based-on-existing-color-series)

"You can create the legend handles using an empty plot with the color based on the colormap and normalization of the scatter plot."

```
sc = plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], s=size, c=df['colors'], edgecolors='none')

lp = lambda i: plt.plot([],color=sc.cmap(sc.norm(i)), ms=np.sqrt(size), mec="none",
                        label="Feature {:g}".format(i), ls="", marker="o")[0]
handles = [lp(i) for i in np.unique(df["colors"])]
plt.legend(handles=handles)
plt.show()
```

So from their code to yours just change assign your plt.scatter to a variable like sc, and replace all the df['colors'] with T.