# Adding legend based on existing color series

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, scatter-plot

I plotted some data using scatter plot and specified it as such:

```
plt.scatter(rna.data['x'], rna.data['y'], s=size,
                    c=rna.data['colors'], edgecolors='none')
```

and the rna.data object is a pandas dataframe that is organized such that each row represents a data point ('x' and 'y' represents the coordinate and 'colors' is an integer between 0-5 representing the color of the point). I grouped the data points into six distinct clusters numbered 0-5, and put the cluster number at each cluster's mean coordinates.

This outputs the following graph:
[image: graph output]

I was wondering how I can add a legend to this plot specifying the color and its corresponding cluster number. `plt.legend()` requires the style code to be in the format such as `red_patch` but it does not seem to take numeric values (or the numeric strings). How can I add this legend using matplotlib then? Is there a way to translate my numeric value color codes to the format that `plt.legend()` takes? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe try check the [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html). Plot your cluster one by one with kwarg `label`. Then use `ax.legend()` which will recognize the `label` and add legends.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create the legend handles using an empty plot with the color based on the colormap and normalization of the scatter plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [np.random.normal(5,2, size=20), np.random.normal(10,1, size=20),
     np.random.normal(5,1, size=20), np.random.normal(10,1, size=20)]
y = [np.random.normal(5,1, size=20), np.random.normal(5,1, size=20),
     np.random.normal(10,2, size=20), np.random.normal(10,2, size=20)]
c = [np.ones(20)*(i+1) for i in range(4)]

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":np.array(x).flatten(), 
                   "y":np.array(y).flatten(), 
                   "colors":np.array(c).flatten()})

size=81
sc = plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], s=size, c=df['colors'], edgecolors='none')

lp = lambda i: plt.plot([],color=sc.cmap(sc.norm(i)), ms=np.sqrt(size), mec="none",
                        label="Feature {:g}".format(i), ls="", marker="o")[0]
handles = [lp(i) for i in np.unique(df["colors"])]
plt.legend(handles=handles)
plt.show()
```

Alternatively you may filter your dataframe by the values in the colors column, e.g. using groubpy, and plot one scatter plot for each feature:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [np.random.normal(5,2, size=20), np.random.normal(10,1, size=20),
     np.random.normal(5,1, size=20), np.random.normal(10,1, size=20)]
y = [np.random.normal(5,1, size=20), np.random.normal(5,1, size=20),
     np.random.normal(10,2, size=20), np.random.normal(10,2, size=20)]
c = [np.ones(20)*(i+1) for i in range(4)]

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":np.array(x).flatten(), 
                   "y":np.array(y).flatten(), 
                   "colors":np.array(c).flatten()})

size=81
cmap = plt.cm.viridis
norm = plt.Normalize(df['colors'].values.min(), df['colors'].values.max())

for i, dff in df.groupby("colors"):
    plt.scatter(dff['x'], dff['y'], s=size, c=cmap(norm(dff['colors'])), 
                edgecolors='none', label="Feature {:g}".format(i))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Both methods produce the same plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ! This works

Answer (score 2):

[Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/) can be a great choice here.

#### Continuous classes

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(40*np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=['A', 'B','C'])

from altair import *
Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(x='A',y='B', color='C').configure_cell(width=200, height=150)
```

[image]

#### Discrete classes

```
df = pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.randn(40, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
df['C'] = np.random.choice(['alpha','beta','gamma','delta'], size=40)

from altair import *
Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(x='A',y='B', color='C').configure_cell(width=200, height=150)
```

[image]